# How to get the value from nested array in php

Tags: php, arrays

When I submit the form by post method i am getting the value like this for an array.

```
 array
 'custom_profile_type' => 
    array
       0 => string '39242' (length=5)
    'satori_programme' => string '0' (length=1)
```

I want the value `39242` from above array. How to get that? Any idea guys ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access it like..

```
echo $yourarray['custom_profile_type'][0];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 echo  $array['custom_profile_type'][0];
```

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran,Ya,misterManSam updated.Thanks,sory for my mistake

Answer (score 3):

Access Using The Below Code | You can add loop to get all values like below

**Static Code**

```
  echo  $array['custom_profile_type'][6]
  echo  $array['custom_profile_type'][0]
```

**Dynamic Code**

```
<?php
$array = $_POST['custom_profile_type'];

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " => " . $value;
}
?>
```